# How to convert init file with Elisp sexps for installing packages to use `use-package`?

Tags: use-package

When I read various guides on how to start using `use-package`, they only seem to describe how to start from scratch.

My init file is full of Elisp snippets I have pasted there, from the installation instructions for various packages.

Since my Eisp powers are very limited, I would really like something like a recipe for how such snippets should be translated into corresponding `use-package` instructions.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some examples of the snippets you would like to convert?

Comment: What @FranBurstall said. The question is to broad/vague. The snippets you mention could be anything at all - there are many Elisp ways to install a package. That can depend on the package and what the Elisp for that package means by "install".

Comment: Its a pity that @Drew edited the question so that it becomes focused on one specific method of conversion. The original version left the door open for several other possibilities, not least a recipe consisting of a series of instructions for a human being.

Comment: The original question left the door open for almost anything. That's the problem - it was too broad. If you want to fish for a broad range of general advice or discussion, try a site such as Reddit. This site is more geared toward specific Q & A, and especially how-to questions or limited questions for conceptual understanding.

Comment: You can check the edit history, to see that my edit didn't change the meaning of your question, except to remove overly broad things like this: *"Does such a recipe exist? Is one even possible?"*.

Comment: Well, look at the answer below, it doesn't seem to use sexps at all. My question was intentionally "overly broad".

Answer (score 5):

Here are some guidelines from my own experience to "bootstrap" your usage of use-package.
(For the reference - you can find my config [here](https://github.com/thatwist/.emacs.d/blob/master/config.org))

1. Right now your config is more or less "linear" or imperative so to speak, while use-package will make it more "declarative".
   The simplest would be to wrap all the code related to a specific package into `:config` section of use-package declaration.
   If there is anything in your config that absolutely must be done before `(require '<pkg>)` (this is rare) - you can put that into `:init` section.
2. Use `:demand t` everywhere at first - lazy loading and dependency handling in use-package can be a little bit of a headache (at first).
   I advise you to be explicit with `:ensure t` in every definition as well (there is an option to enable it globally, but then you may regret later when using something like :quelpa etc.).
3. So now, this is a wrapper for a configuration for every package:

   ```
   (use-package <pkg>
     :demand t :ensure t
     :config
     <move all your configs related to <pkg> here>
   )
   ```
4. There is one trick (not the only) to configure built-in packages with use-package as well - just omit `:ensure t` and use the name of the built-in package (or feature to be more precise, see below), e.g. this is how you can group your `desktop`-related code:

   ```
   (use-package desktop
     :demand t
     :custom
     ((desktop-files-not-to-save "\\(\\`/[^/:]*:\\|(ftp)\\'\\)")
      (desktop-load-locked-desktop t)
      (desktop-buffers-not-to-save ".*")))
   ```

   This is the way to configure `org` and `org-agenda`. There is some confusion in use-package between package-name and feature-name - actually, name that you put right after `use-package` is the name of the `feature` (most of the time the main feature of the package has the same name), to know exactly the name of the feature you can lookup `(provide '<pkg>)` statements in the code of the package. This is sometimes required to know the name of the built-int features (packages) - e.g. `org` and `org-agenda` are separate features, you can group configs into different use-package declarations.
5. Use `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` - this will help you a lot at times when you're confused (especially with lazy loading later) - you should understand that `use-package` just generates plain elisp code, no magic whatsoever.
6. At this point you are "bootstrapped" so you can do next few steps in any order - this will transition you to doing things more in "use-package"-way.
7. Use `:custom`, `:custom-face`. This one is easy, most of the `setq` declarations you should probably move into `:custom` (just remove `setq` part) - see the source code of the variable if it's actually a `defcustom`.
8. Use `:hook`. Whenever you have `(add-hook some-hook (lambda...)` move that into `:hook` removing `-hook` part of the `some-hook` name - e.g. `:hook (some . (lambda))`.
9. Use :bind. Transform your `global-set-key` into `:bind` and your `define-key` into `:bind (:map ...)`. You will have to keep your `evil-define-key` definitions in `:config` though (or use some 'general' extension).
10. Next step - minor transitions to using `:mode`, `:magic`, maybe `bind-keymap`. Use `:if`, `:unless`  if you have something like `(when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)...)`.
11. As a last big move - handle order of loading and execution and migrate your `with-eval-after-load` statements into using `:after` (removing `:demand t` where appropriate). This is a big step as it will remove dependency on the global order of `use-package` declarations (and make your config really declarative).

    The `:after` might be confusing (look pp-macroexpand-last-sexp if you are confused) but equivalent for `with-eval-after-load <pkg2>` would be combination of `(use-package <pkg1> :after <pkg2> :demand t :config ...)`, if you omit `:demand` the execution won't be triggered eagerly after loading `<pkg2>` as use-package will wrap configuration into another `eval-after-load <pkg1>`. Anyway, once you get here you will learn how to debug and figure it out.

    You may want to use `:defer` in some places but I warn you to use `:defer` as a dependency mechanism - use it only to reduce init time and defer loading a fraction of seconds later (this will still block UI anyway but feels smoother) for some packages e.g. `evil`.

    Also at this point it will make more sense to move all functions and variables definitions (defun and defvar) into `:init` block.

    You won't be able to completely get rid of using `with-eval-after-load` as sometimes it is easier to group some configuration under it,
12. Return to use-package documentation (C-h f 'use-package') from time to time until understanding settles in your brain.

Good luck!

Comment: I had a hunch it wasn't trivial, and I was right!

Comment: I bow to the ground and kiss your feet, @Yuri!

Comment: I think I'll bounty this answer 

Comment: Lot of good stuff here. Some things missing... eg some packages are not (m)elpa packages; eg org mode from git. These need a `:load-path` clause